# Discrete Math: Unions, Intersections, Complements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Are these answers correct? The union and intersection only include the elements in the universal set?

$U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$ (where $U$ is only a subset of the Universe)

$A = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12\}$

$B = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$

$A \cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$

$A \cap B = \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$

$(A \cap B)'= \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$

Here is the definition of union given in my book:

$A \cup  B = \{ x \in S | x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\}$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the universal set $S$.

Answer (score 3):

You $A\cup B$ is not correct else everything is correct.

$A\cup B=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$

The definition in the book is absolutely correct.

> The union and intersection only include the elements in the universal set?

true

**EDIT**

> From the answer of Thomas

Note that in problem $U$ is the subset of the universal set. So we can't write all the elements of the complement of $A\cap B$ untill we know the universal set.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I can quickly see is that $B$ contains $0$, so $A\cup B$ should contain $0$.

Also, The complement to $A\cap B$ should contain $0$ if the universe contains $0$.

Comment: Why should 0 be included in the union if it is not in the set U? (Based on the definition of union in the book)

Comment: @BostonMan: The answer to that questions is basically: What is $S$?

Comment: Sir you are right, but there is a problem if we don't know about the universal set then we can't write all the elements of complement of $A\cap B$. Note in problem $U$ is a subset of the universal set.

Comment: @Singh: You can't solve the problem if you don't know the universe.

Comment: Sir that is what I was saying, I have just edited my answer. My brother always says that experience counts in long run. And what you have done is from the experience.  Thank you sir, today I learned to focus from your answer(+1).

Answer (score 0):

We only know that $$U=\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\rbrace \subseteq S$$ where $S$ is the universe. Since $$A\cup B \subseteq S$$ we see that $$U=\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\rbrace \subset S$$ is a more appropriate statement. 
Thus when considering $$(A\cap B)^C$$ we can only say that $$\lbrace 0,1,3,5,7,9,10,11,12\rbrace \subseteq (A\cap B)^C \subset S.$$